# Port forwarding service conflict with an existing port forwarding rule offering Any service

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, port, webcam

I am trying to add a port forwarding rule to my router that will allow a webcam and a 3d print server to run so that I can have remote administration. I am getting the following error

`service conflict with an existing port forwarding rule offering Any service.`

Here's a screenshot of what's going on.

[image]

I have tried to mess with the ports. I made it so that 3344 goes to 3344 and it still gave me the error. I changed any goes to 3344 and it still gives me the error. I see that one of my other computers has a working rule

"TCP Any -> 0-4566"

This new rule doesn't seem much different from that one, but it doesn't work and that one does. I would love to know why this is happening. I am unable to delete the first rule for

"localhost
127.0.0.1   Verizon FiOS Service
Tcp Any -> 4567"

That must be a verizon one. I fear that it may be interfering though. Thanks ahead of time for any help!

Comment: Have you had a Look here to see if this solves your issue?[PortFordaringConflictVerizon](https://forums.verizon.com/t5/Fios-Internet/Port-Forward-Conflicts-with-all-of-them/td-p/107506/page/2)

Answer (score 0):

I think I just figured it out. Some of my rules were overlapping from my other computer. I excluded 3344 from the range of the other one and it works. I apologize for wasting everyone's time. I did not notice that and was having quite a bit of trouble. At least I know now. No thanks to verizon's generic message.